# Apache group authorization with mod_lookup_identity

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, authentication, active-directory, authorization

I need to have some users authenticated against an Active Directory database, and I'd like to use `mod_authnz_pam` over `mod_authnz_ldap` for that. The users will have access to certains folders, restricted by the groups they belong to.

The problem is that `mod_authnz_pam` can authorize users by using `Require valid-user` or `Require user <username>`, but not with `Require group <groupname>` (unless I specify a group file, which is not my intent). I've found out that there's this `mod_lookup_identity`, which works with `mod_authnz_pam`, retrieves group information and stores it into an env var.

My question is, how can I use this env var, which will be set up on user authentication, to authorize this same user?

EDIT: I partially figured it out: I can use `Require env` and/or `Require expr`, referring to the env var, which is `REMOTE_USER_GROUPS` in this case. My problem now is that I'm struggling with `httpd`'s `Require` directive evaluation order. Given the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/sftp
ServerName mysite.com.br
ErrorLog logs/mysite.log
<Directory "/var/www/sftp">
    Options Indexes
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "private area"
    AuthBasicProvider PAM
    AuthPAMService httpd-sssd-auth
    LookupUserGroups REMOTE_USER_GROUPS :
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/sftp/folder01">
    Options Indexes
LookupUserGroups REMOTE_USER_GROUPS :
    <RequireAll>
    Require valid-user
    Require expr reqenv('REMOTE_USER_GROUPS') =~ /group01/
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

I can visualize `folder01` folder when I log in to the server root. But when I try to access the folder itself, I don't even get a chance to authenticate. 403 smashes me out. I'm 100% sure the `Require expr` is working because I can't visualize `folder01` folder when I change the regex to anything that doesn't contains user01's valid group.

Error log shows: `[Fri Jul 29 18:49:51.817402 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 9921] [client 10.221.1.187:32196] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/sftp/user01`

`user01` can access `folder01` if I change the directive from `Require expr` to `Require user user01`.

I found out that when `Require expr` is evaluated, `REMOTE_USER_GROUPS` is SET when I log in to the server root, but UNSET when I log in to the folder, and thus the auhorization fails.

EDIT2: increasing `LogLevel` to `debug` revealed that mod lookup only gets invoked once the whole `Directory` has been authenticated/authorized. That's why the env var is set for the next `Directory` (if you have `Option Indexes` on), but not to the one I log in to. I guess that's the end of the line.